# ViewPager and PagerAdapter in a document reader

Tags: android, android-viewpager

I have a text reader to design and I'm finding it hard to code because of a problem. My external file needs to split into various pages so that it can be set in an adapter view and can be further used by ViewPager class to show it on screen. Kindly help me with this.

Answer (score 1):

If you have not looked at [this post](http://android-developers.blogspot.com/2011/08/horizontal-view-swiping-with-viewpager.html) on the Android Developers Blog post related to ViewPager, it may help.

I think the  question you are asking is, what is the size of the views that you need to break the content (external file) into so that the content fits within the limits of the device your app is running on.  This size can change depending on the device.  Then how to measure how much text will fit in each of these views (since this will also change depending on the size of the display).

The size of the view that you want to put things into can be found by calling getMeasuredWidth() and getMeasuredHeight() but you are going to have to measure all of the text, line by line to size it into the measured view.

Take a look at the [code here](http://code.google.com/p/android-textview-multiline-ellipse/source/browse/trunk/TextViewMultilineEllipse.java).  You may be able to adapt it to build a pager to pour text into each of the views you are paging through. Hope that gets you started.

Comment: Thanks a ton! I will check it.
There is another post that has addressed similar issue:
https://gist.github.com/8ac25178173a1e60f391